# Grub crashes on Apt upgrade (grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory)

Tags: 18.04, grub2, upgrade, grub-efi

I have multiple servers with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. After running **apt-get upgrade** I received this error on each of my servers.

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu44) ...

Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
Failed: grub-install --target=x86_64-efi  
WARNING: Bootloader is not properly installed, system may not be bootable
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.167~18.04.1+2.04-1ubuntu44) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-efi (2.02-2ubuntu8.23) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.47) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried

```
apt-get remove --purge grub*
apt-get install grub-efi
```

I received the same error.

**parted -l**

```
Model: ATA INTEL SSDSC2BB48 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system     Flags
 1      2097kB  538MB  536MB  primary  ext4            boot, raid
 2      538MB   480GB  479GB  primary  ext4            raid
 3      480GB   480GB  536MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA INTEL SSDSC2BB48 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system     Flags
 1      2097kB  538MB  536MB  primary  ext4            boot, raid
 2      538MB   480GB  479GB  primary  ext4            raid
 3      480GB   480GB  536MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md2: 479GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  479GB  479GB  ext4


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md1: 536MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  536MB  536MB  ext4
```

**lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"**

```
NAME    MOUNTPOINT LABEL       SIZE FSTYPE            UUID                                 PARTUUID
sda                          447.1G                                                        
├─sda1                         511M linux_raid_member c364765a-3520-35be-a4d2-adc226fd5302 b6b3ff9d-01
│ └─md1 /boot      /boot       511M ext4              97d71870-bf9f-417c-b574-a2029e1d3957 
├─sda2                       446.1G linux_raid_member 7dd31816-8619-f750-a4d2-adc226fd5302 b6b3ff9d-02
│ └─md2 /          /         446.1G ext4              ff05852d-7f0f-4f80-ab89-cfe3397b6411 
└─sda3  [SWAP]     swap-sda3   511M swap              86e64442-6f61-4606-9e87-18af89b5feab b6b3ff9d-03
sdb                          447.1G                                                        
├─sdb1                         511M linux_raid_member c364765a-3520-35be-a4d2-adc226fd5302 5c50a432-01
│ └─md1 /boot      /boot       511M ext4              97d71870-bf9f-417c-b574-a2029e1d3957 
├─sdb2                       446.1G linux_raid_member 7dd31816-8619-f750-a4d2-adc226fd5302 5c50a432-02
│ └─md2 /          /         446.1G ext4              ff05852d-7f0f-4f80-ab89-cfe3397b6411 
└─sdb3  [SWAP]     swap-sdb3   511M swap              9f3d62fc-3c8c-474c-b844-fe7e325d19a2 5c50a432-03
```

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2    /   ext4    errors=remount-ro,discard   0   1
/dev/md1    /boot   ext4    errors=remount-ro,discard   0   1
/dev/sda3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0
```

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows? If so don't forget to disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: No, I rent servers from soyoustart (ovh)

Comment: Then you need to check with their support.

Comment: fdisk -l shows that I don't have the efi partition. Therefore, as I understand it should use grub-pc instead. When I install grub-pc it automatically installs grub-efi and I receive the error.

Comment: Is install UEFI or BIOS. Or at some point did you delete ESP - efi system partition which is FAT32 with esp/boot flags? If BIOS/MBR grub should just install in BIOS mode to MBR. If UEFI, it needs to know ESP, usually from mount in fstab. Post these: `sudo parted -l` , `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"`
 & `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: ok, I just removed grub-efi and grub-pc, installed only grub-common, grub2-common, run update-grub and everything work ok, system reboots ok.

Comment: I've added the output you asked to the topic.

Comment: That shows it is BIOS install on MBR partitioned drive. Not sure why you would get an UEFI update. You should be using grub-pc which is the BIOS version.

Comment: @antolex3 - I'm having the same issue on the same platform. Please could you share the series of commands that resolved the problem?

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me was :

```
sudo apt remove grub-efi-amd64-signed
sudo apt install grub-pc
```

On a OVH server (kimsufi)

Comment: It didn't work because grub-pc also installed grub-efi-amd64-signed. However, now it works. Seems like they fixed dependencies.

Comment: I had the exact same problem (ubuntu 18.04 server upgrade breaking with this grub EFI message whereas I'm not using EFI). I was a bit surprised to see the EFI packages were installed as I'm not using EFI at all. I was afraid to remove them at first but tried after seeing this and it seems to have worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to have done the trick for me. Is there any way to do a scan or something to make 100% sure everything is fixed? I checked for updates and everything installed without error when it was previously giving out about lots of grub issues, so i think its good but i wanna be sure before i reboot and end up stressed out for the day trying to fix it